# How to downgrade curl on CentOS8?

Tags: centos, curl

How to downgrade curl on CentOS8?

I want downgrade curl: `7.61.1 => 7.29.0`

I tried:

```
yum downgrade curl
```

but no packages marked for downgrade.

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:47 ago on Mon 20 Dec 2021 10:48:20 PM EST.
Package curl of lowest version already installed, cannot downgrade it.
Error: No packages marked for downgrade.
```

also cannot remove it:

```
# rpm -e curl
error: Failed dependencies:
    curl is needed by (installed) rpm-4.14.2-9.el8.x86_64
    curl is needed by (installed) clevis-11-2.el8.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum downgrade` can be used only to downgrade to a version which is available in the repositories. Curl 7.29 was released in 2013 so it definitely isn't available in CentOS 8 repositories (but it was available in CentOS 7). Also as you can see from the `rpm` output, curl is used by rpm itself so removing it is really bad idea.

If you need this old version of curl for testing or some specific application I recommend installing it manually from source to `/opt` or `/usr/local` or using a container.